# Highcharts, graphing precipitation types, volumes and intensity over time

Tags: charts, highcharts, data-visualization

I have an automatic weather station that collects four different types of data for precipitation:

1. On/Off for precipitation event
2. total volume over time period in mm
3. intensity mm/hour and
4. precipitation type

i.e.:

```
0              No precipitation
40             Precipitation present
51             Light drizzle
52             Moderate drizzle
53             Heavy drizzle
```

Stacked bars can manage volume by precipitation type over time.

I would like to graph intensity by type by time. I think changing marker colours based on type is an answer to this. Is there a better solution please?

Comment: Dave, are you looking to plot both precipitation volume and precipitation intensity on the same graph?

Comment: Yes @MikeZavarello tha is what I am aiming for

Comment: Dave, what do you think about using two yAxes and add one series to one axis? Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/csts55kf/1/

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion based on your requirements could be a combination bar and line chart, using dual axes (as Grzegorz Blachliński mentioned).

As you noted, stacked bars would be helpful for showing comparative volume of each precipitation type. You could then overlay lines to show the intensity of each type over time.

I would suggest choosing colors that the user can easily relate to each precipitation type, especially between the two chart types.

Here's a rough draft I coded based on one of the demo charts from the Highcharts website:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Precipitation'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
        },
        yAxis: [{
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Preipitation volume (mm)'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },{
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Preipitation intensity (mm/hr)'
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        legend: {
            //align: 'bottom',
            //x: -30,
            //verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            //y: 25,
            //floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
            borderColor: '#CCC',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                    style: {
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'rain',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
            color: '#b3b3ff'
        }, {
            name: 'sleet',
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1],
            color: '#d9b3ff'
        }, {
            name: 'snow',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
            color: '#c2c2f0'
        },{
            name: 'rain intensity',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
            color: 'blue',
            type: 'line',
            yAxis: 1
        }, {
            name: 'sleet intensity',
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1],
            color: 'purple',
            type: 'line',
            yAxis: 1
        }, {
            name: 'snow intensity',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
            color: 'indigo',
            type: 'line',
            yAxis: 1
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

If you like, you're also welcome to work from this code at the fiddle I created here: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/kbk53n43/

I hope this is helpful for you.

[image]